# Create table with conditional formatting and send it in HTML mail

Tags: html, powershell, azure-powershell

I am using PowerShell Script to check whether certain files are uploaded to my Azure Data Lake Store folder and sending that information via email to my someone. Using the below script, I am using the `if` condition and putting the data in a table whether the file is loaded or not.

Output:

```
FILENAME    STATUS
IMG01       Loaded
IMG02       Loaded
VID01       Not Loaded
```

1. How can I add table borders to this script. The current table is plain without any border.
2. How to use conditional formatting like if it is "Loaded" then the cell should be in green in color and if it is "Not Loaded", the color of the cell should be red.

```bsh
    $filepresent = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -AccountName -Path $path
    $filename = Split-Path $path -Leaf
    if ($filepresent.Count) {
        $row = $table.NewRow()
        $row.FileName = $filename
        $row.Status = "Loaded"
        $table.Rows.Add($row)
    } else {
        $row = $table.NewRow()
        $row.FileName = $filename
        $row.Status = "Not Loaded"
        $table.Rows.Add($row)
    }
}
$html = "<table><tr><td>Dataset</td><td>File</td><td>SLA</td></tr>"
foreach ($row in $table.Rows) {
    $html += $style + "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td><td>" +
             $row[2] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
```

Comment: So your question is not about Powershell at all, but actually *"how can I make text green in HTML"*?

Comment: The other thing... `ConvertTo-Html` should work nice. Add some css to it and you got your table.

Comment: It's probably simpler to manually write the HTML here, b/c then you can put a style or class on a `<td>` depending on the value you're filling in. When using `ConvertTo-Html` you'd have to parse and modify the generated HTML.

Comment: Yes, this helps. This is more of html related issue. I am new to HTML as well. So I can put some conditional formatting in <td> tag and proceed. If my understanding is correct. Right?

Comment: Conditional formatting would be formatting that changes automatically depending on the value of a cell. HTML/CSS doesn't support that AFAIK, hence your code needs to check the value in the cell, and then write the respective (static) formatting instructions to the HTML code along with the value.